# Oracle materialized view refresh on two different schedules

Tags: oracle11g, refresh, materialized-views

Oracle 11g database.  I have a few materialized views that refresh every Sunday morning at 8:00am.  The business has now requested that these same views also be refreshed the last day of each month.  Suggestions on how to accommodate the the additional refresh schedule?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW PO_INVOICES_MV 
...
TABLESPACE USERS
NOCACHE
NOLOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE
START WITH TO_DATE('06-03-2024 08:00:00','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
NEXT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 7 +8/24
WITH PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: Use Scheduler jobs to perform the refresh, not a "next" clause.